# Can't Exit Out of Shop in Jetpack Joyride Playing on AppleTV with AppleTV Remote

Tags: jetpack-joyride

When playing on Apple TV and choosing Shop > Clothing or any of the other Shop > {buttons} the player cannot seem to exit out of that subcategory (e.g. Clothing) and resume the game without either deleting the app and/or restarting the Apple TV. Exiting the game does not reset the view. Looks like a bug...

Comment: You need more detail, currently, I really do not understand what you are asking. Tell me what Apple TV version, what game version, what phone, etc.

Comment: This sounds less like a question and more like a bug report that you should be sending to the makers of Jetpack Joyride.

Answer (score 1):

Recently purchased a game controller and the “B” button works perfectly to exit the store.

We now use Apple TV remote for regular gameplay, and game controller to exit store quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Hm... Seems weird. The game might not support apple tv. I would use every button on the remote to try and exit. If not, try to exit off of your IPad or other device.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and ended up having to delete it and reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

2017 and still the same issue!  If you're on an AppleTV playing Jetpack Joyride, once you are in the Shop - the only way of getting out of it, is to restart the AppleTV.

Answer (score -1):

I have the Apple TV w jet pack joyride and u just have to spam the menu button I promise this works. It works for me